# Python script only working when ran in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

My python code would only run if it was placed into Visual Studio Code. The code still works but when I click on the script to run it, it doesn't work, and when I use a command to run it, it doesn't work either.

```
# importing the module
import time
import wikipedia
import io

# looks for a random page and stores the topic in random
random = wikipedia.random(pages=1)

#searches for the topic and stores it in wiki
wiki = wikipedia.summary((random), sentences = 1) 

# print the output of wiki
file = open("test.txt", "w")
file.write(wiki)
file.close
```

I also have an AutoHotkey script to run it but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Could you share the error it raises?

Comment: Are there any messages when the script is run from command line?

Comment: It doesnt work means what? nothing or you get an error? your code looks ok I guess you have your python path wrong or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could mean that you don't have python added to path.

This is how you add python to path:

```
1. Start the Run box and enter sysdm.cpl
2. In the System Properties window go to the Advanced tab and 
   click the Environment Variables button
3. In the System variable window, find the Path variable and 
   click Edit
4. Position your cursor at the end of the Variable value line 
   and add the path to the python.exe file, preceeded with 
   the semicolon character (;)
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. I also had to make sure that .py extensions open with python, and not Visual Code Studio.

Comment: This will mean you can only use one version of Python.